# Does the potion of clairvoyance require concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, concentration

The *potion of clairvoyance* says:

> When you drink this potion, you gain the effect of the *clairvoyance* spell.

This is different than the *potion of gaseous form* and others:

> When you drink this potion, you gain the effect of the *gaseous form* spell for 1 hour **(no concentration required)** or until you end the effect as a bonus action.

Emphasis mine.

### If a potion granting a spell effect doesn't say "(no concentration required)", must you concentration on it?